# How to connect to postgresql server running on EC2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have a service running on a normal AWS Linux EC2 instance. The backend is postgresql which by default is not exposed to outer world. The instance is exposed by HTTPS for web access to the frontend service only.

I want to use a client to remotely connect to this DB for debug and maintenance purpose from time to time. What are the steps to open it up?

I'd guess following steps maybe?

1. Change config of the DB service to allow it accept connection from outer world?
2. Change EC2 firewall rules to allow external connection to the DB service port (what port)?

Thanks

I haven't tried anything cos I searched but couldn't find any tutorial.

Comment: What do you mean by debug and maintenance on database ?

Why don't you start  one EC2 on the same VPC of your database and connect it from there ?

Still you wouldn't have to expose to the world

Comment: Is the "backend postgresql" running on the same EC2 instance or somewhere else in AWS ?

Comment: @SumitS The DB is running on the same EC2 instance. I have revised my question. This instance provides web access to internet and this postgresql is the backend DB.

Comment: @Sheen - I have given an answer below - does it help?

Comment: @SumitS I installed pgAdmin4 and it natively supports SSH tunneling without any config change!

Answer (score 3):

The safest option would be to **keep your Postgres database inaccessible to the Internet**.

To connect to it, use **SSH Port Forwarding** that will connect your local computer to the EC2 instance.

You would connect to the instance with:

```
ssh -i key.pem -L 5000:localhost:5432 ec2-user@IP-ADDRESS
```

This will redirect local port 5000 (you can choose any number) to the EC2 instance and from that instance it will connect to `localhost:5432`, which is where the Postgres database is running.

Your local SQL client can connect to it via `localhost:5000`, which will forward traffic through the tunnel. The traffic will 'appear' to be coming from the EC2 instance itself, so your database should accept the traffic.

Comment: Hi, when I run your ssh cmd, it launches into a Windows SSH cmd line environment and successfully connect to remote instance. Do you mean I can leave the SSH session alone and kick off my Windows postgresql client now to connect to local port 5000?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: This works! And I've found that SSH tunneling is natively supported by pgAdmin4. Very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response, you need to do two things

1. First ensure that you have firewalls open so you can hit the Postgres service ( by default port 5432 ) from your laptop.
2. Inside the Postgres service there is an additional firewall. If you can connect to it from within the EC2 instance, "show hba_file" will tell you that file location ( in my case it is the default location ). See the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) for what it does

   hba_file

   ---

   /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf